Avoiding style-mismatch with computed value
My goal is to render a list of elements randomly placed inside a grid.
I tried to achieve this with the cue-computed property. But unfortunately I'm always getting the error:
- rendered on server: style="grid-column:12;"
  - expected on client: style="grid-column: 10"
  Note: this mismatch is check-only. The DOM will not be rectified in production due to performance overhead.
  You should fix the source of the mismatch. 

In order to avoid CLS, I don't wanted to first set the visibility of the component to hidden and after placement set it back to visible.
I tried it with the following code:
const computedStyle = computed(() => {
   const letters = '0123456789ABCDEF'
   let color = '#'
   for (let i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
      color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)]
   }
   const style = `background: ${color}; grid-column: ${useRandomnumber(0, 12, 1)} / span 3`

   return style
})

<template>
   <div class="box" ref="item" :style="computedStyle"></div>
</template>

I tried solving this issue with a computed variable. But it doesn't work as expected. The idea behind this choice is, that I also want to adjust the grid-column: _ / span ... properly based on the grid of the viewport with.
But just like I said, I'm always getting the style-mismatch error..

??? Why are you using some random here? The random will be different on the server and client.

@kissu like i said, because I wanted to place this component on a random place inside the grid

Nah, you cannot mix and match random + SSR at the same time unfortunately. You could maybe share the state between the two so that it's random only on the server and then you use the same one for the client. But here you have randoms on both ends so it does not match. You can also run the code only on the client side.
